# How to iterate a keyword for 'n' number of times in robot framework using for loop?

Tags: robotframework

Kindly suggest a way to iterate the "Press Key" keyword using for loop to make it look simpler Instead of having 20 lines of Press key event as mentioned below.

```
Press Key  ${code}  \\097
Press Key  ${code}  \\098
Press Key  ${code}  \\099
Press Key  ${code}  \\100
Press Key  ${code}  \\101
Press Key  ${code}  \\102
Press Key  ${code}  \\103
Press Key  ${code}  \\104
Press Key  ${code}  \\105
Press Key  ${code}  \\106
Press Key  ${code}  \\107
Press Key  ${code}  \\108
Press Key  ${code}  \\109
Press Key  ${code}  \\110
Press Key  ${code}  \\111
Press Key  ${code}  \\112
Press Key  ${code}  \\113
Press Key  ${code}  \\114
Press Key  ${code}  \\115
Press Key  ${code}  \\116
Press Key  ${code}  \\117
```

Comment: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#for-loops

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the loop you can use instead write code many line

```
*** Keywords ***   
PressKeyWithZero
     [Arguments]   ${key_code}  ${code}
     Press Key     ${code} \\0${key_code}
PressKeyNoZero
     [Arguments]   ${key_code} ${code}
     Press Key     ${code} \\${key_code}        
*** Test Cases ***
Keycode_TEST
       ${key_code}=   set variable    97
       : FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    1    20
        \   Run keyword if    ${key_code} <100       PressKeyWithZero     ${key_code}  ${code}
        \   ...    ELSE IF    ${key_code} > 100    PressKeyNoZero   ${key_code}  ${code}
        \  ${key_code}     evaluate  ${key_code}+1
```

Comment: Thanks! But how to repeat this iteration for the two more times to make it as 60 characters input

Comment: @Poovin You should define this as keyword and you can recall it's X time you want .

Comment: Thanks a lot! @Sidara KEO